# Trigger a build asynchronously in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I have a job A running in Jenkins, which kicks off a process A on a VM, waits for it to finish, picks up the report generated by it and sends it as an attachment to the build notification. The problem is this process A takes too long to finish and job A keeps waiting on it. Is there any way I can start this process A, stop job A and when process A is done, trigger a new job B which would pick up the report generated by process A and sends it out with build sucess/failure status.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jenkins provides an API for kicking off jobs via simple HTTP requests.  You kick off job B using `curl` or something like that, as the final step in process A on the VM.

The docs are [on the Jenkins site](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API).  You can use your own Jenkins find the specific URLs for kicking off particular jobs; there's a link in the bottom right hand corner of the Jenkins page.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps an even better match for your use case would be a job of type "Monitor an external job". I have not used it myself, but from the documentation it sounds like a useful tool. The docs are at: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Monitoring+external+jobs